# Drastic reduction in size after using --whole-archive ld option

Tags: linker, ld

`ld` [documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.16/ld/Options.html) says,

> --whole-archive
>
> For each archive mentioned on the command line after the
>   --whole-archive option, include every object file in the archive in the link, rather than searching the archive for the required object
>   files. This is normally used to turn an archive file into a shared
>   library, forcing every object to be included in the resulting shared
>   library. This option may be used more than once.

I have written a toy program and linked it statically with GNU `gmp` library (`libgmp.a`). Surprisingly, the size of `libgmp.a` is `1.2 MB` while that of the resulting executable is `526 KB`. Extracting the `.a` archive using `ar -x` yields `457` object files. According to the documentation, if all of those are linked irrespective of the usage, how come there is almost `50%` reduction in size post linking? Is there any means I can confirm whether all the object files have got linked in the executable or not?

Answer (score 0):

I was curious, so I tried it myself.

I threw an empty `main()` into a source file, compiled it and linked against `libm.a` with `--whole-archive` specified. Then I extracted all object files from `libm.a` and linked against all them.

I used `nm` on both executables, cutted the symbol names out, and `diff`ed the output. It was identical, both executables had 2003 symbols.

I also extracted symbol names from `libm.a` itself and compared them to ones in my executable files. Once again, there were no differences (apart from C runtime symbols in executables, of course).

So I think it's pretty safe to say that `--whole-archive` works exactly as advertised.

As for the drastic difference in size, it is likely to be caused by the fact that object files are full-blown ELF binaries. They are stuffed with information (like ELF headers) that doesn't make it into the resulting executable.

Comment: Exactly, that's the only viable explanation I can think of.